# Count element by starting / ending attribute value in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Current XML is

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <tc rowspan="start">content</tc>
        <tc>content</tc>        
        <tc>content</tc>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <tc rowspan="end"/>
        <tc>content</tc>        
        <tc>content</tc>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <tc rowspan="end"/>
        <tc>content</tc>        
        <tc>content</tc>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <tc>content</tc>
        <tc>content</tc>        
        <tc>content</tc>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Desired output is

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <tc rowspan="3">content</tc>
        <tc>content</tc>        
        <tc>content</tc>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <tc>content</tc>        
        <tc>content</tc>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <tc>content</tc>        
        <tc>content</tc>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <tc>content</tc>
        <tc>content</tc>        
        <tc>content</tc>
    </tr>

</table>
```

There can be more than one table with rowspans in a document and more than one cell with rowspan in the same table, so it is not enough to count the following silbings with a rowspan attribute. Rather I need to count all following siblings until the next `rowspan="start"` occurs.

I assume there is a `for-each-group` solution but couldn't figure out the details.

Furthermore there can be more than one `rowspan` in the same `tr`.

XML example is:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <tc rowspan="start">content</tc>
        <tc rowspan="start">content</tc>
        <tc>content</tc>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <tc rowspan="end">content</tc>
        <tc rowspan="end">content</tc>
        <tc>content</tc>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <tc rowspan="end">content</tc>
        <tc>content</tc>        
        <tc>content</tc>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <tc>content</tc>
        <tc>content</tc>        
        <tc>content</tc>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <tc>content</tc>        
        <tc>content</tc>        
        <tc>content</tc>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Desired output would be:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <tc rowspan="3">content</tc>
        <tc rowspan="2">content</tc>
        <tc>content</tc>
    </tr>
    <tr>


        <tc>content</tc>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <tc>content</tc>        
        <tc>content</tc>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <tc>content</tc>
        <tc>content</tc>        
        <tc>content</tc>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <tc>content</tc>        
        <tc>content</tc>        
        <tc>content</tc>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the edited input sample I think using

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="table">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="tr" group-adjacent="boolean(tc/@rowspan)">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
           <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-starting-with="tr[tc[@rowspan = 'start']]">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
           </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tr/tc[@rowspan = 'start']">
  <tc rowspan="{count(current-group())}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </tc>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tc[@rowspan = 'end']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

should give the correct result.

I still not sure whether that solves your problem as so far we have not seen more complex input samples.

Comment: I was considering offering an XSLT 2.0 solution, too, but wasn't quite sure how to avoid using an explicit match pattern containing `table`. Would `<xsl:template match="*[tr]">` work, too?

Comment: @MarcusRickert, `match="*[tr]` would match any element containing at least one `tr` child, yes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I'm using XSLT 2.0 and Saxon-PE 9.4.0.6. But as far as I have tested it, it counts all `tr` elements whether they have a `rowspan` attribute or not.

Comment: @M.Paetzold, please provide a sample of the input where the suggested solutions fail to produce the result you want and post the result you want as well, then hopefully we understand your requirements better.

Comment: I added a 'normal' tr to the example. In this case I get `rowspan='4'` instead of `rowspan='3'`.

Comment: @M.Paetzold, I have edited the stylesheet to address the edit of input and result samples you have done.

Comment: Thanks, now it is working. There is a following problem with multiple `rowspan`s in a `tr`; I updated the posting.